# For this 2 by 2 locally linear system, how to determine that this "indeterminate" critical point is a centre? Boyce, p516, Question 9.3.12

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, systems-of-equations, proof-explanation

$12.$ (a) Determine all critical points of $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=(1+x)\sin y$ , $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1−x−\cos y$ .
(b) Find the corresponding linear system near each critical point.
(c) Find the eigenvalues of each linear system. What can you conclude about
the nonlinear system?
(d) Draw a phase portrait of the nonlinear system to confirm your conclusions, or **to to extend them in those cases where the linear system does not provide definite information about the nonlinear system.**

12(a) . The critical points are given by the solution set ofthe equations
$(1+x)\sin y=0$ , $1-x-\cos y=0$ .
If $x=-1$, then we must have $\cos y=2$, which is impossible. Therefore $\sin y=0$ , which implies that $y=n\pi$ , $n=0, \pm 1,2,\ \ldots$. Based on the second equation,
$x=1-\cos n\pi. \implies $ The critical points are located at $(0, n_{even} \pi) = (0,2k\pi)$ and $(0, n_{odd} \pi) = (2,\ (2k+1)\pi)$ , where $k=0, \pm 1, \color{red}{ ??? } 2,\ \ldots$.

> **(1)** k is any integer, right? Why didn't solution write $\color{red}{ \pm } 2 $ ?

$(b,\ c)$ . The Jacobian matrix ofthe vector field is
$J=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
\sin y & (1+ & x)\cos y\\
-1 & \sin y & 
\end{array}\right).
$. Then $J(0,2k\pi)\ =\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right),
$
with purely complex eigenvalues $r_{1,2}=\pm i$. The critical points ofthe associated linear systems are centers, which are stable. **Note that [Theorem 9.3.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/804126/87058) does not provide a
definite conclusion regarding the relation between the nature of the critical points of the nonlinear systems and their corresponding linearizations.**

> **(2)** [This table says a center for a linear system is indetermininate, because for a locally linear system, it can be a center or stable point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/804126/87058). But how can you determine that (0,0) is  a center? The solution didn't reveal how it determined this? I know the solution graphed with a computer, but what do I do on an exam?

I skip the details for $
J[2,\ (2k+1)\pi]$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of critical points is
$$
\{(0,2k\pi)\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}\cup\{(2,(2+1)k\pi)\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}.
$$
To determine that $(0,0)$ is indeed a center, an approach is to look for some curve 
$$
y=u(x)
$$ 
invariant by the dynamics. This happens when, for every $t$, 
$$
y'(t)=u'(x(t))x'(t),
$$
This condition holds when, for every $z$,
$$
1-z-\cos u(z)=u'(z)(1+z)\sin u(z),
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\frac{\sin u(z)\cdot u'(z)}{1+z}-\frac{1-\cos u(z)}{(1+z)^2}+\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}=0,
$$
that is,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\left(\frac{1-\cos u(z)}{1+z}+\log(1+z)+\frac1{1+z}\right)=0.
$$
To sum up, the function $V$ defined by
$$
V(x,y)=\frac{2-\cos y}{1+x}+\log(1+x),
$$
is invariant by the dynamics. The point $(0,0)$ coincides with the curve $V=1$ and the cycles around $(0,0)$ are the curves $V=1+\varepsilon$ for small positive values of $\varepsilon$.