# Intuition or wisdom for stability and instability properties of locally linear system. Boyce, p513, Table 9.3.1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, intuition

> [image]

Our instructor requires us to memorize this table for our differential equations exam. So I wonder if anyone has some deeper intuition or observation to help with this?

For example, I noticed that whenever eigenvalues $< 0$, the stability (for linear and locally linear systems) is stable. Why is this?

@snarski I'm terrified too for the exam. I write about the most general eigenvalue, when $r = \lambda \pm iu$. Solutions to $\mathbf{ x' = Ax }$ are, from BOYCE p161, $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}(\cos(ut) + i\sin(ut)).$  So when $\lambda <0$, then $\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} e^{\lambda t}(..) = 0$ ?

Comment: It terrifies me that you have to memorise this table and don't yet know why negative eigenvalues lead to local stability. In order to help you, we'll need to know (i) what you know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $2\times 2$ matrices and how $r_i$ relate to these (ii) what you know about solutions to equations of the form $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))$ and $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)$, where $A$ is a constant coefficient matrix. Please write out explicitly the basic tools you have in your class and what you know about them (where do $r_i$ come from, what is 'local' stability...)

Comment: @snarski i updated my question. please edify me now?

Comment: I can begin to help. What I wanted you to say was that $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of $\lambda^2 - (a+d)\lambda + \det(A)$, where $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}.$ You cite Boyce & Duprima about the general solution, but you need to know how to obtain that solution yourself, and why it makes sense -- can you do this? 

Your comment that if $\lambda < 0$, then $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} x(t) = 0$ is correct and is the reason for local stability.

Comment: To understand local stability, however, you need to understand basic Taylor expansions. In other words, to what extent the approximation $f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + E(x-x_0)$ is valid, where $E$ is the error and $E(x-x_0) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$. In this example $f(x)$ is a real-valued function, but in the case where $f(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x))$, $f'(x_0)$ will be a matrix $Df(x_0)$ (do you know this)?

Answer (score 0):

The imaginary part only adds oscillations to the general magnitude behavior. So the result only depends on the real part of the eigenvalues. Negative real parts have falling eigenfunctions, positive parts have eigenfunctions that grow over all bounds.

To have (asymptotic) stability, you will need all real parts negative.

If only one real part is positive, there is at least one infinitely growing solution starting close to the fixed point, so the fp is instable.

If some real parts are zero (and all the other negative), the growth behavior depends on the multiplicity of the eigenvalue and, in the non-linear case, the higher order terms of the Taylor expansion.

It makes not really much sense to separate this discussion into real and complex eigenvalues, since the important point is their location on the positive or negative real-part half-plane. Of course, the shape of the two-dimensional phase pictures is different for complex conjugate pairs and pairs of unrelated real eigenvalues.